# Помогите понять, почему не работает v-mask при подстановки данных в форму?

Tags: vue.js

```
<label for="executor-phone">Телефон: </label>
        <b-input
          :disabled="!isDataFormEmpty"
          :state="validateState('executor_phone')"
          id="executors-tel"
          v-model="$v.list_of_limit.executor_phone.$model"
          v-mask="'+7 (###) ###-##-##'"
          type="text"
          size="sm"
          placeholder="+7 (812) 123-45-67"
        ></b-input>
```

```
list_of_limit: {
 initiator_code: 302,
 executor_phone: this.user.phone || null,
 list_of_limit_rec: {},
 limit_date: moment(today).format('DD.MM.YYYY'),
 records: 236,
 executor_name: this.user.name,
 lim_type: "S - на начало дня",
 initiator_name: "Комитет финансов СПб",
 currency: "RUB",
 comment: ""
}
```

при получении данных и подстановке для отображения в форму теряется реактивность и форматирование по v-mask не происходит, в чем может быть проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
setDataInForm(readOnlyData) {
      this.list_of_limit = readOnlyData.SPCEX_DOC.document.list_of_limit
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в потере реактивности, чтобы ее вернуть можно создать поле следующим образом, создать поле в модели заново, методом Vue.set()

```
this.$set(this.list_of_limit, 'executor_phone', list_of_limit.executor_phone)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте v-model.lazy="$v.list_of_limit.executor_phone.$model"

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]